# Migrating from PIC32MX to ATSAM MCU - SWD interface doubt

Tags: microcontroller, arm

Currently I use PIC32MX MCUs in my projects, but my new projects are going to have ATSAME5 MCUs onboard. On the PIC32MX I use a 5-pin interface to program and debug using a PICkit4 tool. The signals that I always used with PIC32MX are VCC, GND, MCLR/VPP, DATA-IO/PGD and CLOCK/PGC. For new projects I am going to use ATSAME5 MCUs, and I plan to keep using a 5-pin interface, by using VCC, GND, RESETn, SWDIO and SWCLK. I want to confirm if these group of 5 signals are really enough to program and debug the ATSAM MCUs, because it will be my first project with an ARM core.

Comment: are you asking if you can use the PICkit4 tool to program and debug the ATSAME5x MCU?

Comment: I will buy an ATATMEL-ICE tool to program/debug the ATSAM MCUs. My doubt is if is it enough a 5-pin interface with VCC/GND/RESET/SWDCLK/SWDIO...

Comment: Is it possible to program ATSAM MCU with PICkit4?

Comment: i do not know ... i only commented because your post does not clearly state what you are trying to do ... if you are not planning to use the PICkit4 tool, then the 1st half of your post is irrelevant and only confuses the question ... only the last sentence, with a list of signals,  is actually relevant

Comment: Yes you can program the SAM device with the PICKit 4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you're right, since the SAM E5 family is ARM Cortex based, the 5 signals you mention are the one you need to program a target device in "Serial Wire" mode:

> VCC, GND, RESETn, SWCLK, SWDIO

That's what I have on several designs and it works well (AT SAM and STM32).

But if you want extended debugging features you need to add some more signals. The many documentations about ARM Cortex programming interfaces might help you:

- [CoreSight 10, from the ARM Developers website](https://developer.arm.com/docs/100893/latest/target-interface-connectors/coresight-10-connector)
- [Cortex Debug 10 pin interface, from the ARM Keil documentation](http://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/ulinkpro/ulinkpro_hw_if_jtag10.htm)

Extract from the [ARM Keil documentation](http://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/ulinkpro/ulinkpro_hw_if_jtag10.htm):

```
Signal  | Connects to...
------------------------
SWDIO   | Data I/O pin. Use 100K Ohm pull-up resistor to VCC.
SWO     | **Optional** trace output pin.
SWCLK   | Clock pin. Use 100K Ohm pull-down resistor to GND.
VCC     | Positive Supply Voltage — Power supply for JTAG interface drivers.
GND     | Digital ground.
nRESET  | nRESET pin — Connect this pin to the (active low) reset input of the target CPU. Use 100K Ohm pull-up resistor to VCC. This is an open-collector/open-drain output.
```

Comment: Thanks. Are the pull-down and pull-up really required? On nRESET is ok, but how about SWDIO and SWCLK. They should be push-pull outputs, so what would be the reason for resistors on them? In my case I will have pull-ups ok 10K on both signals because they are shared with other inputs of the board. Thats is, they will be not floating, this should be enough.

Comment: It think it's for the case where the probe is **not** connected. I have a design where the resistors were removed and it works. By the way: where did you get that SWCLK and SWDIO are _push-pull_ signals?